# How do I create a line widget with rounds in its start and end?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been searching for a solution for this both here, and on google with no success.

I want to create a Horizontal line which has dots in the ends.

[This is an example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKw3L.png)

How can I achieve this with css?

i did try to make something but i didn't go much far

```css
.VecBox {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
  box-shadow: 0px -3px 15px 5px rgba(65, 65, 65, 0.07);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.pickDate {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  color: #2F312F;
}

.pickTm {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  color: #2F312F;
}
```

```html
<div class="VecBox">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 w-100 text-left LocationAB pl-5">chembumukku</div>
    <div class="col-6 w-100 text-right LocationAB pr-5">alappuzha</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="VecBox mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="w-100 pl-2 pickDate text-left">07 December 2021</div>
      <div class="w-100 pl-2 pickTm mt-2 text-left">04 : 15 PM</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="w-100 pr-2 pickDate text-right">07 December 2021</div>
      <div class="w-100 pr-2 pickTm mt-2 text-right">04 : 15 PM</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 text-center pickDis">
      2 days and 22 hours
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the`<hr>` element (Horizontal Rule) for the line. Then you can add `pseudo elements` for the circles at the start and end. `Pseudo-elements` are great for adding styles before and after an element without adding unnecessary markup. It can be used to:

> - Style the first letter, or line, of an element.
> - Insert content before, or after, the content of an element

Check out [W3 schools explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) for `::before` and `::after`

```css
hr {
  width: 50%;
  border: dotted red 1px;
}

hr::before {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

hr::after {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25%;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  margin-top: 4px;
  outline: solid red 1px;
  outline-offset: 5px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<br>
<div></div>
<hr>
```

Comment: But i still don't get how do i create a circle at center